# ansible template error while templating string: no filter named 'product'

Tags: ansible

I have the below playbook works fine in ansible 2.9.6 version. But it throws the error while running on ansible 2.4.2.0 version. my requirement is to use the `{{ applog }}` variable in my configuration yaml file with proper indentation and line break.

templates\appconfig.yml.j2

```
paths: {{ applog | indent (width=4, indentfirst=True) }}
```

The output of appconfig.yml

```
    paths: 
       - /home/ketg/apps/ketg_DEV/logs/*.log
       - /home/ketg/apps/ketg_UAT/logs/*.log
       - /home/teng/apps/ketg_PT/logs/*.log
```

playbook to work on both versions. can someone help

**sample-playbook**

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    app_log_paths: "/home/ketg/apps/ketg_DEV/logs/*.log,/home/ketg/apps/ketg_UAT/logs/*.log,/home/teng/apps/ketg_PT/logs/*.log"
 
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        logs: "{{ app_log_paths.split(',') }}"
    - set_fact:
        applogs: "{{ ['- '] | product(logs) | map ('join') | list }}"
    - set_fact:
        applog: "{{ applogs | join('\n') }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ applog }}"
```

### Output ansible 2.9.6

```
PLAY [localhost] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [set_fact] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [set_fact] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [set_fact] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "- /home/ketg/apps/ketg_DEV/logs/*.log\n- /home/ketg/apps/ketg_UAT/logs/*.log\n- /home/teng/apps/ketg_PT/logs/*.log"
}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=5    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

### Output ansible 2.4.2.0

```
TASK [set_fact] ********************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "template error while templating string: no filter named 'product'. String: {{ ['- '] | product(logs) | map ('join') | list }}"}
```

Comment: There is no `product` filter in 2.4.x. One solution is to drop a custom filter plugin into your project that implements the `product` filter.

Comment: Hi @larsks thanks for your response. could you please explain your approach in details. or any other solution equivalent to `product` filter which works in both versions.

Comment: There is documentation [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_plugins.html) about writing your own plugins. This requires writing Python code.

Comment: How are you using these facts in your playbook? Maybe we can think of a way that you won't need to the use the product filter.

Comment: I am using this `{{ applog }}` variable in my configuration yaml file.

`templates\appconfig.yml.j2`

```
  paths:
{{ applog | indent (width=4, indentfirst=True) }}
```
the output will looks like
appconfig.yml

`
 paths: 
    - /home/ketg/apps/ketg_DEV/logs/*.log
    - /home/ketg/apps/ketg_UAT/logs/*.log
    - /home/teng/apps/ketg_PT/logs/*.log
`

Comment: Hi @Aaron unable format the content  properly in the comment section. So updated my question please refer.

Comment: Okay. So to be clear, you only use the applogs and logs variables to construct applog in your playbook?

Comment: Yes @Aaron The applog variable will be used in my appconfig.yml

Comment: Updated my answer. Just realized that appconfig is a template file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In templates\appconfig.yml.j2 loop over the result of splitting app_log_paths on commas and template in the array items as shown below. This should provide the result you're looking for.

You also shouldn't need all of that set_fact logic any longer.

Tested locally on my machine and this behaves as expected. Let me know if it works for you.

```
paths:
{% for path in app_log_paths.split(',') %}
    - {{ path }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: thanks @Aaron. It works as expected. thank you so much for your effort and the swift response.

Comment: No problem!! :)